# Problem with google search and my webpage

Tags: indexing, seo, google-search-console

I have a question, I recentry modified the webpage of the company I'm working at, but when I search the page on the google search console, I receive results of an strange page from Japan, even when my website have just the .pe domain. What could be the reason of that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question since it doesn’t appear to be about programming; it likely makes more sense on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your website probably has a Japanese hack. Check the guide of Google **[Fixing the Japanese keyword hack](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/fixing_the_japanese_keyword_hack)**.

Answer (score 0):

RESTART  NGX AND :
1-REMOVE THE INFECTED CODE FROM index.php because it regenereted again and again an dagain.

2-change all access inside wp-config.php for DB

3-chnage all your hosting login/pass

4-chnage all wordpress login/pass users all of them

5- download new version of wordpress and in you ftp change the
folders wp-admin and wp-include and all themes by default inside wp-content

6-dowload all new vession of plugins you use and delete old in ftp and put new one and activate

7- i buy wordfence i did scan and repair automatic and there is files i did manual i removed eval () functions

8 -redo the scan untill you did not see red point in scanning wordfence

9- and do like vodeo generate the xml

and wait will be fine